# get list item by id using COM sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, com

I need to get item from list sharepoint by Id I use this code and it give me all the items of the list :

```
<script>

function parseURLParams(url) {
        var queryStart = url.indexOf("?") + 1,
            queryEnd = url.indexOf("#") + 1 || url.length + 1,
            query = url.slice(queryStart, queryEnd - 1),
            pairs = query.replace(/\+/g, " ").split("&"),
            parms = {}, i, n, v, nv;

        if (query === url || query === "") {
            return;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            nv = pairs[i].split("=");
            n = decodeURIComponent(nv[0]);
            v = decodeURIComponent(nv[1]);

            if (!parms.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                parms[n] = [];
            }

            parms[n].push(nv.length === 2 ? v : null);
        }
        return parms;
    }
 $( window ).load(function() {
  var urlString = document.URL;
 urlParams = parseURLParams(urlString);

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveActualite, "sp.js");

        var siteUrl = '/sites/securite';

    function retrieveActualite() {

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Actualite');
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=”ID” LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Text">' + urlParams.IdArt[0] + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceededActualite, onQueryFailed);
        }

        function onQuerySucceededActualite(sender, args) {

            var listItemInfo = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

           while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();


                var desc=oListItem.get_item('Description');
                $('#idArticle').append('<label class="titleArticle">'+oListItem.get_item('Title')+'</label> <br><br><p class="ContenuArticle" >'+desc+'</p>');             
            }
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }


    });



</script>
```

so how can I get only the considered item ?

Comment: I think it should be <FieldRef Name="ID"><Value Type="Integer">. No LookupId attribute, and type integer.

Comment: Did you realice ID is enclosed between strange characters? ”ID”, It should be "ID".

Comment: I tried <Value Type="Integer">  but it still give me all list items

Comment: Did you remove LookupId attribute?

Comment: Your query returns all items since it is malformed, the value for set_viewXml method should contain View root element

Comment: Yes  Vadim, I should add the root

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Value for [SP.CamlQuery.viewXml property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246871.aspx) should always contains the `View` root element:

```
<View>
   <Query>...</Query>
</View>
```

---

There is no need to perform CAML query to return List Item by id, use [SP.List.getItemById Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019.aspx) for that purpose.

Secondly, SharePoint JavaScript library already includes functions for parsing query string, for example `GetUrlKeyValue`.

Example

```
function getListItem(listId,itemId,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_web();
   var list = web.get_lists().getById(listId);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   ctx.load(item);

   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(item); 
      },
      error);
}





var listId = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));

getListItem(listId,itemId, 
   function(item){
       console.log(item.get_item('Title'));
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you need three fields corresponding to the list item you are searching for - name, age, city. Here is how the code for the same looks like, assuming **'Name', 'Age'** and **'City'** are the **internal names** -

```
var itemId = 'yourItemID';   
var listName = 'yourListName';
var targetListItem;

function getListDetails(itemId) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); 
  var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
  targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(itemId);
  clientContext.load(targetListItem, 'Name');
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {   
   var myName = targetListItem.get_item('Name');
   var myAge= targetListItem.get_item('Age');
   var myCity= targetListItem.get_item('City');
   alert('Name: ' + myName +'\n'+ 'Age: ' + myAge + '\n' + 'City: '+ myCity);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
   alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```